# Isomorphism and Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, vector-space-isomorphism

I started reading Linear algebra done wrong and am confused at a theorem that he leaves the proof off to the reader. The Theorem is if A: V -> W is an isomorphism, and v1, v2, ... vn are a basis in V. Then the system Av1, ..., Avn is a basis in W. 
I had tried a proof and attached it below but it is wrong I am almost certain. I have made no use of the face that there is an Isomorphism between the Spaces where does that come in and why is my proof not complete and or correct? 
[image]

Comment: Where is the proof of linear independence? Also, given a $v\in V$, you could let $w = \mathcal Av$, not that $v \in V, w\in W$ then $\mathcal Av = w$.

Comment: Would the proof of linear independence use the face that there is an isomorphism? Also how does the second part help? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $w\in W$, there exists $v\in V$ such that $Av=w$ because A is surjective.

Since $v_1,...v_n$ form a basis for $V$, $v=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$ for some $a_i$ and $Av=A(a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n)=a_1Av_1+...a_nAv_n=w$. Therefore, the $Av_i$ span $W$.

Suppose $b_1Av_1 +...+b_nAv_n=0$.

$b_1Av_1 +...+b_nAv_n=A(b_1v_1+...+b_nv_n)$ by linearity. Since $A$ is an isomorphism it is injective so $b_1v_1+...+b_nv_n=0$.

Therefore, $b_1v_1+...+b_nv_n=0\implies b_i = 0$ for all $i$ because the $v_i$s form a basis and so are linearly independent. Since the $b_i$s are all $0$, $Av_1,...,Av_n$ are linearly independent and therefore, a basis.

Comment: Thanks for this! One thing though span hasn't been defined yet  so could you explain that bit using something different maybe?

Comment: It just means that each vector in $W$ can be expressed as a linear combination of  the $Av_i$.

Comment: Doesn't that alone make it a basis?

Comment: Also why is isomorphism needed to say that b1v1 + ... bnvn = 0? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: No. Add another vector to your basis. That set is no longer a basis because it is not linerarly independent but it still spans your space. You just don't use the extra vector.

Comment: If $A$ is not injective then there could be non-zero solutions to the equation.

Comment: I think I have it please correct me if I am wrong, if the transformation was not an isomorphism then there could be multiple values ofv going to Av, then there will be different values of b_i such that Av = 0 some not necessarily 0. Thus it will not be a basis. Is this why it must be isomorphic or is this rubbish? Thanks again

Comment: @jakewalsh It sounds like you got it.

Comment: Thanks John a lot clearer now

Answer (score 1):

I can't say John's solution is wrong. However, Treil's book is rigorous. By this point, he hasn't mentioned surjective at all. I think his intention is to use the definition. Here is my take.
[image]